# What's the syntax to add a calendar reminder from Google Command Line?

Tags: command-line, google-calendar, syntax

I've been using googlecl successfully to add events to my calendar. Things like:

```
google calendar add "call Paul tomorrow at 8:30am"
```

work great, and add the appropriate event t the right time. But no reminder is added for the event.
I tried:

```
google calendar add "call Paul tomorrow at 8:30am reminder 10 minutes"
```

and other combinations. It just ends up adding the "reminder" instruction to the event description.

What's the syntax I should use to add a, let's say, 10 minutes pop-up reminder?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments section on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/ExampleScripts), there isn't a way to do it.

Comment: I see one comment asking the question - I don't see a negative answer

Comment: And I surmised from the lack of information on the page, along with that comment, that it is not possible.